# In a Python list, how can I print the 1st and 2nd elements on a line, the 3rd and 4th on the next line, and so forth?

Tags: python

I am generating a string and appending it to a list. I am looping that action to make a list of 40 elements. I want to print them like so:

here's my list

```
list = [ 'first', 'second', 'third', ... 'fortieth' ]
```

i tried this

```
for z in list:
if z % 2 == 0:
    print(list[z], list[z+1])
```

and many other variations. i want it to print like this

```
first second
third fourth
fifth sixth
...
thirty-ninth fortieth
```

how can i do this?
thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please provide [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: seriously? downvote? how is this not clear enough? i will add some extremely obvious code for your satisfaction. of course i have tried things. why would i be asking if i hadn't tried things? do you think this is the kind of feedback i was looking for?

why not just say nothing since you obviously don't know how to answer my question

Comment: The down vote is not mine and the rest of your assumptions is also wrong. Have a nice day.

Comment: Wow, @grcHIDDEN, responding like that isn't a great way to get help from strangers. "i will add some extremely obvious code for your satisfaction". You add the code **so we can see what you've done** and so we can point out **what changes you could make** without having to write the entire thing **for you**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Printing 2 values on a list is as simple as creating a for loop that skips over every other value. When you create a for loop, you can use `range(start,stop,interval)` to accomplish this. Then you can just fill in the two print statements using the for loop

I hope that this will work for you:

```
for x in range(0,len(listtest),2):
    print (listtest[x], listtest[x+1])
```

replace `testlist` with your list's name

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name, as its already a built-in function.

Secondly you can get every *odd* indexed item by slicing `[::2]`, and every *even* indexed item with [`1::2]`, which is show below:

```
>>> my_list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
>>> print(my_list[::2])
['first', 'third', 'fifth']
>>> print(my_list[1::2])
['second', 'fourth', 'sixth']
```

Then you can just [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together and print them:

```
my_list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']

for x, y in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]):
    print(x, y)
```

Which outputs:

```
first second
third fourth
fifth sixth
```

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty straightforward.  you write a for loop.  go through the list.  for every odd number--if line number mod 2 == 1; then, print a newline.  print("\n")

unless there is something special about the list that you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a loop and iterate the list.
Since you have 40 elements it's easy

```
i=0
while(i<40):
    print(list[i]," ",list[i+1])
    i=i+2
```

Comment: This terrible practice, but also hilarious. Not sure who downvoted you since it works